# Search based on a set of keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I need to make a search based on a set of keywords, that return all the Ads related with those keywords. Then the result is a list of Categories with the Ads Count for each Category.

The search is made in a KeywordSearch Table:

```
public class KeywordSearch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

Where the Keyword Table is:

```
public class Keyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Ads are related with the Keywords using the following Table:

```
public class KeywordAdCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Keyword_Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Keyword_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Ad_Id", Order = 1)]
    public int Ad_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Category_Id", Order = 2)]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the Category table:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

- Keywords: "Mercedes-Benz" and "GLK"
- KeywordSearch: "Mercedes" and "Benz" for the Keyword "Mercedes-Benz"
                "GLK" for the Keyword "GLK"
- Category: "Cars" and "Trucks"
- Ads: Car - Mercedes-Benz GLK
      Truck - Mercedes-Benz Citan

  If I search "Mercedes-Benz" I get:

  - Cars: 1
  - Trucks: 1

  If I search "Mercedes-Benz GLK" I get:

  - Cars: 1

  If I search "Mercedes Citan" I get:

  - Trucks: 1

What I get until now:

```
var keywordIds = from k in keywordSearchQuery
                    where splitKeywords.Contains(k.Name)
                    select k.Keyword.Id;

var matchingKac = from kac in keywordAdCategoryQuery
                    where keywordIds.Distinct().Contains(kac.Keyword_Id)
                    select kac;

var addIDs = from kac in matchingKac
             group kac by kac.Ad_Id into d
             where d.Count() == splitKeywords.Count()
             select d.Key;

var groupedKac = from kac in keywordAdCategoryQuery
                    where addIDs.Contains(kac.Ad_Id)               <--- EDIT2
                    group kac by new { kac.Category_Id, kac.Ad_Id };

var result = from grp in groupedKac
                group grp by grp.Key.Category_Id into final
                join c in categoryQuery on final.Key equals c.Id
                select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
                {
                    Id = final.Key,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    ListController = c.ListController,
                    ListAction = c.ListAction,
                    SearchCount = final.Count()
                };
```

The problem is that I can't get only the Ads that match all Keywords.

EDIT:

When a keyword is made of 2 or more KeywordSearches like "Mercedes-Benz", the line "where d.Count() == splitKeywords.Count()" fails, because d.count = 1 and splitkeywords.Count = 2 for "Mercedes-Benz"

Any Help?

Comment: Possibly instead of using "where ... contains(...)" see the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407729/determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq

Comment: 1. Please clarify what you mean with > Ads: Car - Mercedes-Benz GLK Truck - Mercedes-Benz Citan

Comment: 2. As far as I understand "Mercedes-Benz GLK" matches "Mercedes", "Benz" and "GLK". That means both keywords "Mercedes-Benz" and "GLK" are found. "Mercedes-Benz" is a car and a truck, "GLK" is a car. That means two cars and one truck are found. I hope this is somewhat of a help because it's difficult to provide an answer without clarifing point 1 first.

PS: I wasn't aware of the 5 minute edit limit.

Comment: @Kabbalah - Hi, thanks! The problem here is to get the Category Counts based on a set of keywordSearches. When a keyword is made of 2 or more KeywordSearches, the line "where d.Count() == splitKeywords.Count()" fails, because d.count = 1 and splitkeywords.Count = 2 for "Mercedes-Benz".

Comment: @Patrick For what are you using addIds? It doesn't seem to used anywhere.

Comment: So sorry, I corrected it in EDIT2

Comment: Why your model is incomplete? I mean why KeywordAdCategory does not contain respective navigation properties? Is it like that or you have only posted partial code and your full model does contain respective navigation properties?

Comment: Hi, it's a join table for relashionship between Keywords, Ads, and Categories

Comment: @Patrick, I know its relation, but why doesn't it contain Keyword, Category navigation properties? It is possible to create any type of query if you have all navigation properties for every relation and you do not need to use any Joins.

Comment: @Akash Kava - it's the way I do it using EF, is there a better way to do it? Can you show me an example? Thanks

Comment: Wrong hammer for the job. Use full text search.

Answer (score 2):

this may not be the direct answer, but in such "multiple parameter search" situations i just forget about anything and do the simple thing, for ex: Search By Car Manufacturer, CategoryId, MillageMax, Price :

```
var searchResults = from c in carDb.Cars
where (c.Manufacturer.Contains(Manufacturer) || Manufacturer == null) &&
                 (c.CategoryId == CategoryId || CategoryId == null) &&
                    (c.Millage <= MillageMax || MillageMax== null) &&
                          (c.Price <= Price  || Price == null) 
select c
```

now if any of the parameters is `null` it cancels the containing line by making the whole expression in brackets `True` and so it does not take a part in search any more

Comment: i like the pyramid effect :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make your own search engine you will probably fail.Why don't you try Lucene.
Here's a link http://lucenenet.apache.org/.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I haven't compile-checked this or anything, so it may require some tweaking, but you're looking for something along these lines.

```
var matchingKac = keywordIds.Distinct().ToList()
    .Aggregate(
        keywordAdCategoryQuery.AsQueryable(),
        (q, id) => q.Where(kac => kac.Keyword_Id == id));
```

You're effectively saying, "Start with `keywordAdCategoryQuery`, and for each keyword add a `.Where()` condition saying that it must have that keyword in it. You could do the same thing with a `for` loop if you find `Aggregate` difficult to read.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick answer, but I getting the error: "Error  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @Patrick: Like I said, I haven't tried this in a compiler. Try debugging it yourself: probably you need to switch `id` and `q` around.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm not able to get it running. Any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick: I can't help you without knowing what's wrong. Is it not compiling? What's the error message? You're really going to have to do as much as you can for yourself.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm not able to get it running. Any help would be nice. I have Switch id with q but I get the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Heelp.Domain.KeywordAdCategory] Aggregate[Int32,IQueryable`1] Thanks

Comment: I get null in matchingKac

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution now. This is based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298167/select-distinct-records-from-list-of-keywords) and a few assumptions:

1. Keywords are complete names like "Mercedes-Benz GLK", "Mercedes-Benz Citan".
2. KeywordSearchs are "Mercedes", "Benz" and "GLK" for "Mercedes-Benz GLK" and "Mercedes", "Benz" and "Citan" for "Mercedes-Benz Citan"
3. "Mercedes-Benz GLK" is a "Car", "Mercedes-Benz Citan" is a "Truck"

With those three assumptions in mind I can say that

```
var keywordIds = from k in keywordSearchQuery
                 where splitKeywords.Contains(k.Name)
                 select k.Keyword.Id;
```

is the culprit and all queries below rely on it. This query will find all keywords that contain any words in your searchstring.

Example: Given searchstring "Mercedes-Benz GLK" will be split into "Mercedes", "Benz" and "GLK". Your query now finds "Mercedes" and "Benz" in both "Mercedes-Benz GLK" and "Mercedes-Benz Citan".
I think it's obvious that you don't want "Mercedes-Benz GLK" to match "Mercedes-Benz Citan".

The solution is to tell the query to match every splitKeywords with any Keywordsearch and return the appropriate Keyword:

```
var keywordIds = keywordSearchQuery
                 .GroupBy(k => k.Keyword.Id)
                 .Where(g => splitKeywords.All(w => 
                                               g.Any(k => k.Name.Contains(w))))
                 .Select(g => g.Key);
```

As for addIds changing it to `var addIDs = matchingKac.Select(ad => ad.Ad_Id).Distinct();` should do the trick. Or if matchingKac is only needed in addIds then you could change it to

```
var matchingKac = (from kac in keywordAdCategoryQuery
                   where keywordIds.Distinct().Contains(kac.Keyword_Id)
                   select kac.Ad_Id).Distinct();
```

and remove addIds.

Comment: Hi, thanks but your query to get all the Keyword Ids is not working. To understand, each Keyword is composed by a set of KeywordSearch so Mercedes-Benz Keyword is composed by the keywordSearch "Mercedes" and "Benz" and the keywordSearch "Citan" is related with the keyword "Citan". If I search "Mercedes Citan" or "Mercedes-Benz" or "Benz Citan" or Benz Mercedes Citan", I always get: Cars = 1, because I have an Ad in KeywordAdCategory that macth the Keyword "Mercedes-Benz" and "Citan".

Comment: The Count of Ads for each Category

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to add regex and omit that special characters and then use Linq for that

So Mercedez-Benz  can become Mercedez and benz

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to NOT define keywords to objects that way, because you might search and find too many objects or you'll find possibly nothing. You will always spoil your time when searching. Classify your objects in a way that the users focus is to FIND and not to search.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer to: https://github.com/n074v41l4bl34u/StackOverflow19796132
Feel free to review it.

Here is the most important snippet.

---

with:

```
internal class SearchDomain
{
  public List<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
  public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
  public List<KeywordAdCategory> KeywordAdCategories { get; set; }
}
```

---

then:

```
private static char[] keywordPartsSplitter = new char[] { ' ', '-' };

internal static Dictionary<Category, Dictionary<int, List<KeywordAdCategory>>> FromStringInput(string searchPhrase, SearchDomain searchDomain)
{
  var identifiedKeywords = searchPhrase
    .Split(keywordPartsSplitter);

  var knownKeywordParts = identifiedKeywords
    .Where
    (ik =>
      searchDomain
      .Keywords
      .SelectMany(x => x.GetKeywordParts())
      .Any(kp => kp.Equals(ik, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    );

  var keywordkSearches = knownKeywordParts
    .Select((kkp, n) => new KeywordSearch()
    {
      Id = n,
      Name = kkp,
      Keyword = searchDomain
        .Keywords
        .Single
        (k =>
          k.GetKeywordParts()
            .Any(kp => kp.Equals(kkp, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        )
    });

  var relevantKeywords = keywordkSearches
    .Select(ks => ks.Keyword)
    .Distinct();

  var keywordAdCategoriesByCategory = searchDomain.Categories
    .GroupJoin
    (
      searchDomain.KeywordAdCategories,
      c => c.Id,
      kac => kac.Category_Id,
      (c, kac) => new { Category = c, AdKeywordsForCategory = kac }
    );

  var relevantKeywordAdCategories = keywordAdCategoriesByCategory
    .Where
    (kacbk =>
      relevantKeywords
        .All
        (rk =>
          kacbk
            .AdKeywordsForCategory
            .Any(kac => kac.Keyword_Id == rk.Id)
        )
    );

  var foundAdsInCategories = relevantKeywordAdCategories
    .ToDictionary
    (rkac =>
      rkac.Category,
      rkac => rkac.AdKeywordsForCategory
        .GroupBy(g => g.Ad_Id)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList())
    );

  return foundAdsInCategories;
}
```

---

It does exactly what you want however I find something fishy about keywords being divisible to sub-keywords. Than again, maybe it is just the naming.